# Configuring MOXy's @XmlPath with XML containing CDATA

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am trying to use XPath to map an XML document via [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php). But it encounters problems when the XML contains CDATA tag Example:

```xml
<![CDATA[Jill's Box Company]]>
```

I am using eclipselink-2.3.0  jar to get the XPath mappings in my application. 
and to make JAXB use this implementation I am creating a `jaxb.properties` file which contains following:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

XPath only works this way, else the application doesn't even pick up the annotation `@XmlPath`.

Now while running and XML through and unmarshaller method it throws a null pointer error as follows:

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.UnmarshalRecord.startCDATA(UnmarshalRecord.java:1035)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLReader$LexicalHandlerWrapper.startCDATA(XMLReader.java:226)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startCDATA(AbstractSAXParser.java:625)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:487)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.WebLogicXMLReader.parse(WebLogicXMLReader.java:133)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader.parse(RegistryXMLReader.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLReader.parse(XMLReader.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:713)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:269)
    at com.jbhunt.lib.mgintegrationutils.utils.JAXBUtils.unmarshal(JAXBUtils.java:67)
    at com.jbhunt.biz.mgarListener.mq.converter.MgarListenerMQMessageParser.getMasterARStagingVo(MgarListenerMQMessageParser.java:51)
    at com.jbhunt.biz.mgarListener.mq.MgarListenerMessageConsumerImpl.onMessage(MgarListenerMessageConsumerImpl.java:62)
    at com.jbhunt.biz.mgarListener.mq.JMSMessageProcessor.receiveAndProcessMessage(JMSMessageProcessor.java:106)
    at com.jbhunt.biz.mgarListener.thread.MessageProcessorThread.run(MessageProcessorThread.java:46)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: "XPath to parse an XML via JAXB" - these words make no sense when strung together in that order. Perhaps you should post your *actual* code, then maybe someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Could you post your object model?  Also I see you are using EclipseLink 2.3.0 the current release is 2.4.1 if you are able to upgrade:  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

Comment: Hi Blaise, I updated the eclipse version to 2.4.1 and it solved the CDATA issue I was facing. Its all Good now.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

> Hi Blaise, I updated the eclipse version to 2.4.1 and it solved the
>   CDATA issue I was facing. Its all Good now.

I'm happy to hear everything is working now.  Below is an article about what's new in MOXy in EclipseLink 2.4:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/06/eclipselink-24-release-available-for.html

---

Since you are using EclipseLink 2.3.0, I believe you are hitting the following bug which was fixed in EclipseLink 2.3.1.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/357145

EclipseLink is currently at version 2.4.1, I recommend upgrading to that if you can:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/